# How to Find all Classes that has specific annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have a several classes like

```
public class price{
@Valid
private Date startDate;
}
```

Now i want all classes that similarly uses @Valid annotation.

This is my code

```
public void abc() {
         ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);

                scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Valid.class));

                for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(packageName)){
                    System.out.println(bd.getBeanClassName());
      }

   }
```

But somehow i don't get any class in output.
P.S i have checked the same implementation for @Entity annotation applied for class level and works fine for the same, but not for annotation used at variable level. I need to know if the implementation is different for field level annotation

Comment: Your `@Valid` is not applied to the class, but to a field...

Comment: Yes indeed, I need to find classes that has @Valid applied to a field